# Change the innerHTML content using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, innerhtml

```
var user;
(function (user) {
    user = {
        dynamicPriceChange: function () {
            $("input[name='user[plan_id]']").change(function (e) {
                var planId = $(this).data('text');
                var durationPlan = $('p#durSubsMY')[0].innerHTML;
                var price = $('.price')[0].innerHTML;
                $('.price').text(planId);
                $('span#Love')[0].innerHTML = price;
                if price == "29" {
                    durationPlan = "per month";
                }
                if price == "261" {
                    durationPlan = "per year";
                }
            });
        }
        jQuery(function () {
            user.dynamicPriceChange();
        });
    })(user)
```

I'm trying to change `durationPlan` as "per month" if the price is 29 & "per year" if the price is 261.
But I'm unable to change that. Please help, I'm new to jQuery.

The Working Corrected Code is

```
    if (price == "29") {
         $('p#durSubsMY')[0].innerHTML = "per month"
        }
    if (price == "261" ){
         $('p#durSubsMY')[0].innerHTML = "per year"
        }
```

Thanks everybody for your help !!!

Cheers ! :-)

Comment: Also I would suggest using === instead of == http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`durationPlan` is just a variable that contains the innerHTML of the element changing its value does not alter the elements content. Try instead

```
    if (price == "29") {
        $('p#durSubsMY')[0].innerHTML = "per month"
    }
    else if (price == "261") {
        $('p#durSubsMY')[0].innerHTML = "per year"
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrong syntax of if statement, you missed the if condition part parenthesis.

*Change*

```
if price == "29" {
       durationPlan = "per month"
}
```

if price == "261" {
         durationPlan = "per year"
   }

*To*

```
if (price == "29") {
      durationPlan = "per month"
}
if (price == "261" ){
     durationPlan = "per year"
}
```

One of closing bracket is also missing in the end.

*Change*

```
})(user)
```

*To*

```
}})(user)
```

Comment: ALWAYS make a fiddle before posting a question in javascript :)

Comment: OP also appears to be missing a closing bracket `}` at the end of his code. Might be nice to add to the answer.

Comment: Adil its effecting my other functionality, i mean that i have written few more functions whose functionality got affected by writing this, how do i keep them unchanged. Sorry but how to get everything working ?

Comment: ok....thanx adil & everybody here for such a quick response to solve my prob, i was stuck since yesterday. Thanks everyone....

Answer (score 2):

As #Adil mentioned, you forgot you parenthesis in the if statement. Also you can try `html()` function from the jQuery library http://api.jquery.com/html/  instead of `innerHTML`.

`var planId = $(this).data('text');`
if you want to get the value from the input use `var planId = $(this).val()`